# Ionic change navbar color dynamically

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have to change the color of the navbar of one page when scrolling a bit.

Here we have part of my xml file:

```
<ion-header no-border>

  <ion-navbar color="{{ toolbar_color }}">
    <ion-title (click)="change()">{{userdata.Name}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen class="container" (ionScrollEnd)="scrollHandler($event)">
```

I tryed first by changing it using a click event and it worked fine.

```
change() {
    if ( this.toolbar_color == "danger" ) {
      this.toolbar_color = "light"
    } else {
      this.toolbar_color = "danger"
    }
}
```

And this is the ionScrollEnd listener, that does not work. The event is fired correctly, but the changes on toolbar_color are not taking any effect on the navbar.

```
scrollHandler(event) {
    if ( event.scrollTop > 100 ) {
      console.log("ScrollEvent --> "+JSON.stringify(event));
      this.toolbar_color = "light"
      // this.toolbar_change = true;
    } else {
      this.toolbar_color = "danger"
      // this.toolbar_change = false;
    }
}
```

How the hell can I do this?

Thank you :)

Comment: well in ionic we use HTML not XML :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@ViewChild(Content) content: Content` in the TS file and subscribe to scroll end event. refer this link for [working version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-scroll-subscribe). Also see the ionic [forum discussion on this issue](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/scrolling-event-in-ion-content/55563)

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
  Arr = Array; //Array type captured in a variable
  num:number = 1000;
  toolbar_color: string;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public ref : ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.toolbar_color="secondary";
  }

  changeColor(){
    this.toolbar_color="primary";
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    //this.content.enableJsScroll();
    this.content.ionScrollEnd.subscribe(() => {
        this.changeColor();
    });
}

}
```

HTML file

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar [color]="toolbar_color">
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
  <p>
    This starter project comes with simple tabs-based layout for apps
    that are going to primarily use a Tabbed UI.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <div  *ngFor="let i of Arr(num).fill(1)">{{i}}</div>

</ion-content>
```

**Update-1**

1. Added code to change color on scrolling
2. Sometimes angular will not run changeDetector automatically. we can manually trigger it by using ChangeDetectorRef. it's added to detect the changes while scrolling.
3. Working version is also updated. Please check the above link

Comment: I will try this, ty. But my scrollEnd event is fireing correctlly, the problem is that the changes on the atribute toolbar_color are not taking effect if come from the scroll event.

Comment: Still not working. Enters the event at the end of the scroll, but does not change the color.

Comment: Change to [color]="toolbar_color" and try.

Comment: code and working version is modified to detect color changes on scrolling

Comment: have you checked this working version https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-scroll-subscribe. ?

Comment: Hehe, sry I missed the ChangeDetectorRef part. Thank you for all Prithivi! You saved my life :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)