# How can I change ion-navbar color dynamically?

Tags: ionic-framework, styles, ionic3, navbar

I have seen multiple post, about changing the ion-navbar color using colors defined in variables.scss.

But here is my scenario: I am consuming a service which (along with other data) returns a hex color that should be set for the nav bar. So setting a color in the variable.scss beforehand is not possible. How can I set the nav bar color as soon as I receive the hex from the service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic change navbar color dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47287327/ionic-change-navbar-color-dynamically)

Comment: @SurajRao It's not the same scenario. He is changing the color by using already stored colors in the variable.scss. I do not know the colors beforehand, I get the hex in runtime.